# Dynamically build input fields after deletion start index from the highest number?

Tags: javascript, jquery, indexing

I have from where user should be able to add new rows. My logic works fine and all new fields get unique `id's` and `names` but the problem occurs when I delete any other row but the last one. Here is example of my code:

```js
$("#add_row").on('click', addRow);

function addRow() {
  var index = $(".data-list").children('div').length + 1;
  console.log(index);

  $('.data-list').append(
    '<div class="form-group required data-item">' +
    '<label class="control-label" for="colddesc"><span class="label label-default">Column & Description:</span></label>' +
    '<div class="row">' +
    '<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-2 col-lg-2">' +
    '<select class="form-control" name="frm_column' + index + '" id="frm_column' + index + '" required>' +
    '<option value="">--Choose--</option>' +
    '<option value="1">Record ID</option>' +
    '<option value="2">Name</option>' +
    '<option value="3">Year</option>' +
    '</select>' +
    '</div>' +
    '<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-10 col-lg-10">' +
    '<div class="input-group">' +
    '<input class="form-control" type="text" name="frm_descr' + index + '" id="frm_descr' + index + '" placeholder="Enter Description" required>' +
    '<span class="input-group-btn">' +
    '<button class="btn btn-danger btn-remove" type="button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></button>' +
    '</span>' +
    '</div>' +
    '</div>' +
    '</div>' +
    '</div>'
  );
};

$(document.body).on('click', '.btn-remove', function() {
  $(this).closest('.data-item').remove();
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="data-section">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
      <button type="button" class="btn" name="add_row" id="add_row">
                                                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign"></span> Add Row
                                                    </button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="data-list">
    <div class="form-group required data-item">
      <label class="control-label" for="coldesc"><span class="label label-default">Column & Description:</span></label>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-2 col-lg-2">
          <select class="form-control" name="frm_column1" id="frm_column1" required>
            <option value="">--Choose--</option>
            <option value="1">Record ID</option>
            <option value="2">Name</option>
            <option value="3">Year</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-10 col-lg-10">
          <input class="form-control" type="text" name="frm_descr1" id="frm_descr1" placeholder="Enter Description" required>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

If I add two more rows (total number of rows 3) and delete the second row, then next time when user clicks on `Add Row` index will start from `3` and that index already exists. I'm wondering how to work around this problem? Is there a good way to start index from the last highest number?

Comment: Why not keep a counter and start from there? After all, you just need it to be unique right?

Comment: @AlainCruz I was wondering what is the best way to keep counter index? Yes, I just need each index to be unique.

Comment: Well, I would just keep a var with the last id assigned. Every time you add a new one, I would just add one to it.

Comment: @AlainCruz Can you please provide an example? Thank you.

Comment: I just did. Hope this solves your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a var where you will keep the last id assigned. Every time you add a new one, I would just add one to it. This way, you will always get unique ids and names for your inputs. You can check the following snippet to see what I mean.

```js
$("#add_row").on('click', addRow);
var counter = 1;

function addRow() {
  counter++;
  console.log(counter);
  $('.data-list').append(
    '<div class="form-group required data-item">' +
    '<label class="control-label" for="colddesc"><span class="label label-default">Column & Description:</span></label>' +
    '<div class="row">' +
    '<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-2 col-lg-2">' +
    '<select class="form-control" name="frm_column' + counter + '" id="frm_column' + counter + '" required>' +
    '<option value="">--Choose--</option>' +
    '<option value="1">Record ID</option>' +
    '<option value="2">Name</option>' +
    '<option value="3">Year</option>' +
    '</select>' +
    '</div>' +
    '<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-10 col-lg-10">' +
    '<div class="input-group">' +
    '<input class="form-control" type="text" name="frm_descr' + counter + '" id="frm_descr' + counter + '" placeholder="Enter Description" required>' +
    '<span class="input-group-btn">' +
    '<button class="btn btn-danger btn-remove" type="button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></button>' +
    '</span>' +
    '</div>' +
    '</div>' +
    '</div>' +
    '</div>'
  );
};

$(document.body).on('click', '.btn-remove', function() {
  $(this).closest('.data-item').remove();
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="data-section">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
      <button type="button" class="btn" name="add_row" id="add_row">
                                                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign"></span> Add Row
                                                    </button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="data-list">
    <div class="form-group required data-item">
      <label class="control-label" for="coldesc"><span class="label label-default">Column & Description:</span></label>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-2 col-lg-2">
          <select class="form-control" name="frm_column1" id="frm_column1" required>
            <option value="">--Choose--</option>
            <option value="1">Record ID</option>
            <option value="2">Name</option>
            <option value="3">Year</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-10 col-lg-10">
          <input class="form-control" type="text" name="frm_descr1" id="frm_descr1" placeholder="Enter Description" required>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```